# How do I make it so that my app remembers the current route on page refresh (using react-router and express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I currently am developing a react app and am using react routes for the first time. I am using express to serve my index.html which is using a babel compiled bumble to display my react.

My navbar works fine when clicking on the links and correctly takes the user to the correct component page but if you click refresh after navigating to a new page it will give me a cannot get page (I realize that its because express isnt serving those specific URLS) I'm kind of stumped here i'll give some of my code

**index.js (react)**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import Budget from './components/Budget.jsx';
import BudgetList from './components/BudgetList.jsx';
import Login from './components/Login.jsx';
import Signup from './components/Signup.jsx';
import history from "./history";

const routing = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/BudgetList" component={BudgetList} />
        <Route path="/Budget" component={Budget} />
        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**navbar (react where i'm linking on click to other pages)**

```
import styles from './modules/nav.module.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.nav_container}>
        <div className={styles.title}><i className="fas fa-calculator"></i> ez<span>Budget</span></div>
        <div className={styles.links}>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to={'./Login'}>Login</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'./Signup'}>Signup</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'./BudgetList'}>Budgets</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Navbar;
```

**server**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('there was a problem connecting ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Listening on port ', PORT);
  }
})
```

Please let me know if i'm not giving enough information, I usually would try and troubleshoot on my own for longer but i'm stumped. Please go easy on me :D

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I switched BrowserRouter as Router to just Router and then added the following in my express:

```
app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  await res.sendFile(`${process.cwd()}/public/index.html`, (err) => {
      if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err)
      }
  })
});
```